# jQuery remove larger scope?

Tags: jquery

If I have an element nested as:

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="/blah.jpg" class="removeme" /></li>
    <li><img src="/ole.jpg" class="keepme" /></li>
</ul>
```

How do I go about removing the entire list containing the img class that has `removeme`?
I've been able to get to

alert($(containername).children('ul').children('li').children().hasClass("removeme"))

returns true but I can't seem to remove the entire `<li></li>` (and **not** only the img).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('img.removeme').closest('li').remove();
```

Should do it.

The problem with parents() is that it could potentially remove more than 1 `<li>` if the list is nested.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the subtle difference between 'parents' and 'closest'. jQuery never ceases to amaze me.

Comment: Good call on `.closest` vs `.parents`, I've deleted my earlier answer since yours is an improvement.

Comment: Actually I needed the parent() implementation more so because I had to first select the right ul. Thanks, both!